# Angular 4 caching

Tags: angular, angular-cache

Problem:

1. I have to display large amount of data
2. Use pagination that can change count (user can select display 10 / 20 /50 per page)
3. Was trying using rxjs following link https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html
4. But I have 2 issues using this....

   4.1. This gives the latest data but I need to display data for that particular page and also display the same when I come back again

   4.2. I use a search on top which requires me to use the whole data but since this caching gets data in steps I will have issue when user searches before the complete data is pulled from the backend service...

Please suggest the best way to accommodate this issue....

Comment: Can you please add stackblitz of what you have done so far ?

Comment: Hi I am using the same code as in the example. Its working and fetching data from my backend service. But all of the data in one go as it normally does and every 10secs thereafter....so Do I need to make any changes even in the backend to ensure I get only certain count of data every 10secs or whenever I click on a certain page number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RXJS subjects have 3 different types of feeds, as far as

```
 1) if you miss it you miss it = Subject   
 2) give me the last value =  BehaviorSubject   
 3) give me all the last values = ReplaySubject
```

it sounds like you're looking for #3 correct?
If so, just look into ReplaySubjects.

Subject - a subscriber will only get published values that were emitted after the subscription. A

BehaviorSubject - the last value is cached. An subscriber will get the latest value upon initial subscription.

ReplaySubject - it can cache up to a specified number of emissions. Any subscribers will get all the cached values upon subscription.

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs";

const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(2, 100);

// subscriber 1
subject.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Subscriber A:', data);
});

setInterval(() => subject.next(Math.random()), 200);

// subscriber 2
setTimeout(() => {
  subject.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Subscriber B:', data);
  });
}, 1000)
```

> We create the ReplaySubject and specify that we only want to store the
>   last 2 values, but no longer than a 100 ms We start emiting Subject
>   values every 200 ms. Subscriber A will pick this up and log every
>   value that’s being emited by the Subject. We start subscribing with
>   Subscriber B, but we do that after 1000 ms. This means that 5 values
>   have already been emitted by the Subject before we start subscribing.
>   When we created the Subject we specified that we wanted to store max 2
>   values, but no longer then 100ms. This means that after a 1000 ms,
>   when Subscriber B starts subscribing, it will only receive 1 value as
>   the subject emits values every 200ms.

Comment: Hey Yes I am using ReplaySubject for this. 
When I call my backend service I am receiving the whole data at a time as in the normal case so Do I need to make any changes even in the backend to ensure I get only certain count of data every 10secs or whenever I click on a certain page number?

Comment: after you are connected to the subject you will get them as they come in

Comment: i gave a little more information, I hope that helps

Comment: hey thanks it has been helpful I am working on this... will update here once things come to a conclusion....

Comment: any luck? @nirajak